# What is the shape of error object inside axios request interceptor error handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

**Technical note:** *As axios uses different libraries/mechanisms for Node and browser, this question touches only `Node.js` usage of `axios@0.18.0`.*

I can set up the following interceptor for the `axios` library ( https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors ):

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    //
    // I am asking about this error handler and this error object
    //
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

**When the callback described in error handler for request interceptor is triggered and and what is the shape of that error object?**

*P.S.* I see that there is [this code describing work with errors](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) in `axios`:

```
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      //
      //
      //  !!!! This is a request error handler !!!
      //
      //
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```

**What will the `error` inside the request error handler represent in the latter code?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When the callback described in error handler for request interceptor
>   is triggered and and what is the shape of that error object?

the error handler (.catch clause) will be triggered by the interceptor, when it "rejects" a promise like in this part of your code:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error); // <---- HERE
  });
```

The shape of the axios error object is a JSON object as stated on the [handling error section of axios docs on github](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

- **message**: the error message text.
- **response**: the response object (if received) as described in the previous section. Inside response you will have data, status, and headers objects
- **request**: the actual XMLHttpRequest object when running on browser or **an instance of http.ClientRequest in node.js.**
- **config**: the original request configuration.

> What will the error inside the request error handler represent in the
>   latter code?

It will be the error response from the request bypassed by your axios interceptor

Answer (score 7):

I think this source code might help you:

[createError.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.18.0/lib/core/createError.js)

It looks like an instance of [Error](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_error), so it has `error.message`, and `axios` adds `error.config`, `error.code`, `error.request` and `error.response`, per [enhanceError.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v0.18.0/lib/core/enhanceError.js).